# Wrapper not resizing to full content size

Tags: css, html, height

I have a div called #background. I have most of my content in it and I want it to resize when I add more content. As far as I know the way to do this is to assign it no height?

I have done this in my layout.css file.

As far as I can see, my #background doesnt close until after the last bit of content which is what I want, but it's not working. It seems to be just stopping after my #special offers div, I#m not sure why this is?

Colm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any background div but a backdrop one..
I guess this is the one you are talking about. You should assign "overflow: auto;" to it.

Comment: Yeah I'm always updating the code man, sorry. The backdrop is the correct div. There was some problems with the my training, library etc divs not clearing. Overflow has fixed it though, thanks dude! :)

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure none of its content elements are not floated, and if there are (or better yet in any case) just put a `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` just before you end the #background div.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the reply. I've since changed the code a bit, I added that div a while ago myself....I thought it seemed like a roundabout way of doing it though?